# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Mac OS to swap windows between two monitors?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I use Mac OS and have a dual monitor setup. One of the monitors (primary) is right infront of me, the other one (secondary) is placed at an angle. So it's easier to look at the primary than the secondary. I would like the primary monitor to show the application that I am actively working on, and the secondary to show other things like a long running command.

Is there any key board shortcut in Mac to swap the windows between the monitors ? That way, I can have always the primary monitor show the application that I am actively working on.

I know I can do that by going to System preference -> Display and then shifting the primary bar from one monitor to other. But that's pretty tedious, a keyboard shortcut would make the process much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one built into the OS natively, but [this answer over on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103830/50295) shows how you can do it with an AppleScript, a third party tool, and binding that script to a hotkey.

There's another application (paid) called BetterTouchTool [that has this functionality built in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another)

For reference, what you're doing here by dragging the bar over is setting the primary display.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer. But thank you sir, your answer was really helpful.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! The best thing you can do is click the checkbox under your answer - that marks it as accepted for the next person who comes along and sees this question :)

Comment: > "The best thing you can do is click the checkbox under your answer"
You meant under your answer ? I can't find any checkbox on this page though.

Comment: NVM found it finally. Thanks Mikey !